# Disable close of last tab in Firefox

Tags: windows, firefox

If I only have one tab open in Firefox and I close that tab Firefox exits.

How do I disable this behaviour?

A solution that prevents me to from closing the last tab **or** opens a new empty tab (or my homepage) is equally acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also add an extension like Tab Mix Plus.

Here's a screenshot of the config page. You can do one of two things:

1. Click the "Do not close window when closing last tab" option to open a new blank tab
2. Select the "Prevent last tab from closing"

[image]

Comment: I chose this answer since I already had Tab Mix Plus installed

Answer (score 6):

there's an about:config tweak that should do this: `browser.tabs.closeWindowWithLastTab` set it to false.

Comment: clean way of handling this situation without an extension